# SSL/TSL issue when attempting to post message from PowerShell to Slack

Tags: powershell, ssl, tls1.2, slack

I am trying to post a message from PowerShell to Slack, this has actually worked previously but stopped for some unknown reason.

This is my PowerShell script, it's quite simple...

```
Import-Module PSSlack
Import-Module $PSScriptRoot\SlackMessageSelfCheck.psm1

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12



    # Check if nagging of the alert has been switched off before checking (:thumbsup:#)

    if (SlackCanWeNag -alertNum 0 -outofHours $true){
            $title = 'Warning System Self Check - Everything is A-OK'
            $text  = "The JT PowerShell warning system is working"
            $text += "`n"
            $text += "`n _This is a system self check which runs every morning_"

                SlackSend -title $title `
                          -text $text `
                          -alertType General `
                          -iconEmoji :thumbsup:
         }
```

but when I run it, I get this error

```
Send-SlackApi : Slack API call failed: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PSSlack\1.0.2\Public\Find-SlackMessage.ps1:95 char:25
+             $response = Send-SlackApi @params
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Net.WebException,Send-SlackApi
Send-SlackApi : Slack API call failed: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PSSlack\1.0.2\Public\Find-SlackMessage.ps1:95 char:25
+             $response = Send-SlackApi @params
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Net.WebException,Send-SlackApi
Send-SlackApi : Slack API call failed: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PSSlack\1.0.2\Public\Send-SlackMessage.ps1:357 char:29
+ ... $response = Send-SlackApi @ProxyParam -Method chat.postMessage -Body  ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Net.WebException,Send-SlackApi
```

I don't understand what the issue is here, as I am specifying the tls12 security protocol.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

I've tried upgrading PowerShell, turning off the firewall, turning of anti-virus.

Comment: The code example is not powershell, otherwise the error you are getting is from Powershell and not Slack, I work with Slack API through powershell but not using PSSlack, and I never had to enable TLS for that, so its possible the issue be unrelated to the PSSlack module.

Comment: The error indicates the connection did not complete and you reached a time out issue.  This type error can be caused by SSL/TLS but also can be caused by lots of other reasons.  You are sending a request from client to server and the connection is timing out.  The server may not be running, you may not have a route from client to server, or the connection is not completing because of credentials/authentication.  SSL/TLS is performed before the request is sent to establish an encrypted connection.  SSL/TLS uses a certificate that may have expired or changes since code was working.

Comment: I believe something changed since 16th of Nov 2023 on Slack side. I have an API that has been working on windows 7 for a few years. It stopped working with similar SSL/TLS certificate issue. I tried everything and couldn't get it to work again. I thought it could be because windows 7's extended support might have finished and somehow caused this issue but I strongly doubt that. I also noticed Slack launched its new interface around 20th of Nov 2023. So I wonder if they messed something up. To be fair, that same API still works if I run it on windows 10.

Comment: just additional info, an identical script to this works perfectly fine on a server running windows 10.  This server runs windows 8.1, so I agree with @Stackedup that I too think Slack have changed something with their latest release.  Authentication runs from a token, there is no issue with the token, it is valid and works.

Comment: Did you get it to work? what version of powershell are we looking at? you could use curl and run this commands to retrieve some logs :

`curl -F "text=test" -F "channel=mychannel" -H "Authorization: Bearer xoxp-bla" -X POST https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage --insecure --trace -`

Comment: In case this can help, since November 15th 2023 I had an handshake_failure (SSLHandshakeException) when running in prod with Java 8. 

I was able to make it work by changing the version of Java to 11. With Java 8 it was working on my local machine not in Google Cloud Dataflow.